# What causes Google Apps Script to fail to execute sporadically?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple script that processes data from Forms and sends it to another Sheets document. Everything looks fine except there have been some cases when the script does not execute at all. I can see in the log that there has been a successful execution at 10:21 and 11:53 but there also should have been one at 10:52. Since there is no execution, there isn't any failure message so there is a great chance I end up missing some submissions. What could be the cause?

The script is triggered on form submit.

```
function extractAndRemoveUrl(text) {
  // Ensure that text is a string
  if (typeof text !== 'string') {
    return { url: "", text: "" };
  }

  var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/;
  var match = text.match(urlRegex);
  if (match) {
    var url = match[0];
    var updatedText = text.replace(url, '').trim();
    return { url: url, text: updatedText };
  }
  return { url: "", text: text };text
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var targetDocumentId = "xxx-id";
  var targetSheetName = "xxx";

  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetDocumentId);
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);

  if (!targetSheet) {
    throw new Error('The sheet named "' + targetSheetName + '" does not exist.');
  }

  var formData = e.namedValues;

  // Check if 'Submission content' exists and has at least one item before accessing it
  if (!formData['Submission content'] || formData['Submission content'].length === 0) {
    Logger.log("No 'Submission content' data found");
    return;
  }

  var content = formData['Submission content'][0].split('\n');

  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var contentTrimmed = content[i].trim();
    if (contentTrimmed !== '') {
      var result = extractAndRemoveUrl(contentTrimmed);
      var newRow = [
        formData['Title 1'][0] || "", // Column 1
        result.text, // Column 2
        result.url, // Column 3
        formData['Title 2'][0] || "", // Column 4
        "", // Column 5
        "", // Column 6
        "", // Column 7
        "", // Column 8
        formData['Email address'][0] || "", // Column 9
        formData['Timestamp'][0] || "" // Column 10
      ];

      targetSheet.appendRow(newRow);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is your script triggered? Please share the initial code as well for reference.

Comment: GAS onFormSubmit triggers are known to inextricably fail on occasion.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot I think you meant to use the word `inexplicably`

Comment: @Cooper I stand corrected. Pity we only have a 5 minutes to edit a comment...